# Page resizing because of the scroll bar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm using jquery to collapse many div tag in my pages but the page is resizing when i collapse the div because of the vertical scroll bar in the page.. i tried fixing the width of the page it did not solve my problem so how can i fix this? i just need to collapse my div without effecting any resizing of the page..

please note that i'm using asp.net with vb.net

```
<div class="content-module">
    <div class="content-module-heading cf">
        <h3 class="fl">Table of content</h3>
        <span class="fr expand-collapse-text">Click to collapse</span>
        <span style="display: none;" class="fr expand-collapse-text initial-expand">Click to expand</span>
    </div> <!-- end content-module-heading -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind i fixed :

```
html
{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```